# Skip Spaces in line.startswith() function in Python

Tags: python

How can I search for a line which starts with "xyz" by skipping spaces?
Original string is "   xyz" by using line.startswith()

Comment: `" xyz ".strip().startswith('xyz')`

Answer (score 8):

`str.startswith` does not skip spaces.  You could use a regular expression (RE) like `r"^\s*xyz"` but it is not worth it because of the overhead in loading and running the RE engine. You might as well create a temporary string object that does not have leading whitespace.  It does not have to be named, but used like this:

```
original.lstrip().startswith('xyz')
```

The temporary string object will become a candidate for garbage collection at once.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex to search for lines which start with 'xyz' even if they may or may not have a space before the 'xyz' by using - `^\s*xyz`

`^` - looks for the start of a line

`\s*` - matches 0-any number of space characters

`xyz` - the term you are interested in matching.

To get the full line you can use `^\s*xyz.*?$` to match the full line

here `.*?` is a non greedy search for any character while `$` is the end of the line

Comment: Looks costly to use regex for such a simple task. Cost to be assessed that being said.

Comment: @Kanak Depending on the number of cases of `xyz` it could be faster than numerous `str.startswith()` checks but yes in general it is more expensive

Comment: Why bother matching the rest of the line when you are not capturing it?  Anyway, in this case, `.*?$` has the same effect as `.*`.  You only need end-of-text `$` *because* you are using a minimal (non-greedy) match.

Comment: @cdarke I left out the brackets for the capture and I thought if you set the multi-line flag to get matches from say a document you need to mention the `$` or is my understanding flawed ?

Comment: OK, but that goes way beyond what the OP was asking.  The question is pretty basic and obviously the OP is inexperienced with python.  Your solution is looking for a different question.